# Mongoose.connect is not connecting to local db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a simple MERN blogging app with a local MongoDB. Everything was working fine until yesterday. I literally changed nothing at all and now I can't connect to my local DB with my Express app while a connection via MongoDB Compass is working fine. Also if I connect to MongoDB Atlas it's also working fine in my Express app.

Tried restarting brew services and updating mongodb-community and mongoose but nothing seems to work.

**Code to connect:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_LOCAL, {}) // DATABASE_CLOUD = mongodb://localhost:27017/seo-blog
  .then(() => console.log("Database connected!"));
```

**Error I get from the server:**

````
Server is running on port: 8000
/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:796
  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:796:32)
    at /Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:329:10
    at /Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1150:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:328:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/server.js:22:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 410689241,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:293:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/tallestguy/Documents/Projects/seo-blog/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:267:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v17.0.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...```
````

Comment: Try using "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/" as localhost URI string.

Comment: Ermagawd, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change "localhost" for 127.0.0.1